# Angular: How to pass Large scale data To an .ashx file( Generic Handler) with $http post method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my first question and i really need help.

Im trying to send large scale JSON string from my conroller to a generic handler using $http post method .But when ever the controll hits the http method the control is getting Lost without giving any error ,I tried my best to solve ,as i am a beginner to angular js, can anybody help me to solve this issue ....

```
       $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'FinjHandler.ashx',                              
            params: { SaveJournal: JSON.stringify($scope.ViewData.FilterData) },                
        }).success(function (RetData) {
         alert('Saved');
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure that the API requires `text/plain`? Normally JSON data is posted as `application/json`.

Comment: Thanks for replying ,I tried with application/json ,text/plain and even without the "headers" option  inside $http ,It works if it is having less data .Actually the json string length is coming near to  2000 charecters only .but still i cant post data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With POST requests the data should be specified with the `data` property of the config object:

```
  $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'FinjHandler.ashx',
        //contenttype: '',                
        //params: { SaveJournal: JSON.stringify($scope.ViewData) },
        //USE data property
        data: $scope.ViewData,
        /*
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text / plain',
            'Content-Length': $scope.paramsLength
        },*/              

    }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
         // Handle success
        var data = response.data;
        var status = response.status;
        var statusText = response.statusText;
        var headers = response.headers;
        var config = response.config;
        //...
        alert('saved');
    }, function onError(response) {
       // Handle error
       var data = response.data;
       var status = response.status;
       var statusText = response.statusText;
       var headers = response.headers;
       var config = response.config;
       //...
    });
```

With the `params` property, the framework URLencodes the data and appends it to the URL as search parameters. The POST data normally does not use the URL for data as percent-encoding is very inefficient.

The AngularJS framework automatically encodes JavaScript objects or arrays into JSON format UTF-8 strings. It uses the `application/json` as the default content type.

For binary data, set the `Content-Type` header to `undefined`:

```
 //FOR FormData, files, and blobs
 headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
```

By setting the content type to undefined, the AngularJS framework will omit the default setting of `application/json` and the XHR API will set the content type appropriately.

Comment: Wow That Just Work Like a Charm...Thank you very much ,One more doubt ,How can i grab the data from ashx ? Previously I am using var Key = (this.Context.Request.QueryString).AllKeys[0]; to get the key and the associated  data